# Audience rule – slow compilation

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, audiences

I’ve got a problem witch audience rule – I have create new rule on Monday, but this rule are not compile. Is there any solution to start / compile manually? Or where I can set the interval between compilations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, directly after you open the Audience for edit you have multiple links, one of them is Compile Audience. Have you tried that?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't Compile audience. I use SharePoint Online (Office 365).

Comment: Ahhh...in Office 365 you don't get access to CA, of course. As for the interval I believe there is a timer job that runs automatically every 7 to 11 days, so it might be that your Audience hasn't been even compiled at all just yet. Do you have access to O365 Administration? In the guide it seems that you can change that.

Comment: Thats clearly answer! :) thanks for information.
One more - can I change this job timer?
Yes, I have access to O365 Administration.

Comment: http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/966.aspx

Answer (score 2):

No it can't,

Audiences are compiled once a week in Sharepoint Online so this feature is useless in more complex scenarios.